# Squaring ListView items using a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I am trying to style a `ListView` in my project, and I'd like its items to be squared.
Below is my current state based on answers I found online.

My `ListView`:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Grid.Row="1"
              Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding RibbonItemList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RibbonPagesListItemTemplate}" />
```

and here's my try at squaring the `ListView`s `ItemTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="RibbonPagesListItemTemplate" DataType="x:Type AppPage">
    <Grid Width="Auto" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualWidth}">
        <Image Height="25" Width="25" Source="{Binding Path=ImgSrc}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

However, the above does *not* work, and I can't find an explanation or a suitable solution.
How could I make this work?

Comment: what does "squaring" the items mean? what doesn't work? what error message do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the whole item container (i.e. the element that is highlighted upon hovering or selection) to be square, rather than trying to accomplish it with `ItemTemplate`, which is used to define the appearance of item inside the container, you should style the item container itself using `ItemContainerStyle` property:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
          Background="Transparent"
          ItemsSource="{Binding RibbonItemList}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RibbonPagesListItemTemplate}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Width"
                    Value="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

You can then remove the `Grid` from your item template.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your model class is called AppPage and it looks something like this

```
public class AppPage
{
    //Other props
    public Uri ImgSrc { get; set; }      
}
```

the only mistake that i can see in your Xaml is the way you are specifying the DataType, this is how it should be :

DataType="{x:Type yourNameSpace:AppPage}"

but that won't affect the result, your code works, and you can verify that by setting a none squared content :

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="RibbonPagesListItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type yourNameSpace:AppPage}">
        <Grid   Background="White" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualWidth}">
            <Image Height="25" Width="70" Source="{Binding Path=ImgSrc}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Background="Black">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
          Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding RibbonItemList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RibbonPagesListItemTemplate}" >           
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Result:

[image]